# How to access folder which is outside war file?

Tags: java, tomcat, pdf

I have application which is having lots of PDF files , when I try to build a war file of my application due to pdfs its size converts to Gbz , so basically I want to remove the pdf file folder from the application ,put it some location and then build a war file and deploy it to tomcat.so ,is there any way I can read folder from my application which is outside the war file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a separe folder on your server to store the pdf. You pass this folder location to your application (for example using globaresouces in server.xml, so your production path and local path are coming from the server rather than hardcoded in your app.). You access the given folder normally from java (new File(dir), Paths.get...). If there is no SecurityManager you can access any part of the filesystem from within your webapp.

For example your aplication META-INF/context.xml

```
<Context>
  <ResourceLink global="PDFPath" name="PDFPath" type="java.lang.String"/>
</Context>
```

Your tomcat, inside server.xml

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
<Environment name="PDFPath" value="D:\\Data\\PDFs" type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

In your code:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context)initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
String storagePath = (String) getContext().lookup("PDFPath");
File pdfDir = new File(storagePath);
```

Comment: <context docBase="" path"/xx alisases ="/xx = local Drive path">.......but it is not able to resolve the path, it says can not find the path, is it this work only when folder resides within tomcat?

Comment: no, this configure where your webapplication will be deployed, then every time you will re-deploy it would be deleted. You need to have a folder outside tomcat/webapp folder (and leave the defaults as they were before you know more). I edited the answer how you can do it:

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class to work with files and directories on the local file system.

For example if if your pdf files are in a folder called pdf you can create a File object like so

`File pdfsFolder = new File("\pdfs");`

Answer (score 0):

ya its correct way but give the Tomcat user permission to access the Pdf file , which is use to avoid the file listing when the time of directly  url access Ex ([www.yourSite.com/pdf/ex.pdf](http://www.yourSite.com/pdf/ex.pdf))

Comment: It's not really helpful to answer a question that was asked 5 years and 9 months ago.